# Jquery auto complete hover css

Tags: css

Hi im trying to style my jquery autocomplete, all is well but when i tried to hover on the items its displaying on a bottom left side of my page, any suggestions to fix this? here is my css code.

```
 .ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;   
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the parent element `position:relative;`?

Comment: top:100% is the problem

Comment: Ok so setting the max-heigth and overflow to auto did the trick, just need to change the background color when hover.